# tables wrapping to next line when width 100%

Tags: css

I'm encountering some weirdness with tables in css.
The layout is fairly simple, a fixed-width nav bar on the left and the content on the right.  When the content includes a table with a width of 100% the table ends up getting pushed down until it has room to take up the full width of the screen (instead of just the area to the right of the nav bar).  If I remove the width=100% from the table's css, then it looks fine, but obviously the table doesn't grow to fill the space of the div.  The problem is that i want the table to grow and shrink with the window but still stay in the bounds of its div.

Thanks.

Here's a simple example:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
    "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
    <head>
        <title>Test</title>

        <style type="text/css">
            #content {
                padding-right:20px;
                background:white;
                overflow:hidden;
                margin:20px;
            }
            #content .column {
                position:relative;
                padding-bottom: 20010px;  
                margin-bottom: -20000px; 
            }
            #center {
                width:100%;
                padding-top:15px;
            }
            body {
                min-width:700px;
            }
            #left {
                width: 330px;
                padding: 0 10px;
                padding-top:10px;
                float:left;
            }
            .tableData {
                width:100%;
            }
        </style>

    </head>
    <body>

        <div id="content">
            <div class="column" id="left">
                <div>
                    Some text goes in here<br/>
                    some more text<br/>
                    some more text<br/>
                    some more text<br/>
                    some more text<br/>
                    some more text<br/>
                </div>
            </div>

            <div class="column" id="center">
                Some text at the top;
                <hr/>
                <table class="tableData">
                    <thead>
                        <tr><th>A</th><th>B</th><th>C</th></tr>
                    </thead>
                    <tbody>
                        <tr>
                            <td>A1 A1 A1 A1</td>
                            <td>B1 B1 B1 B1</td>
                            <td>C1 C1 C1 C1 C</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>A2 A2 A2 A2 </td>
                            <td>B2 B2 B2 B2 </td>
                            <td>C2 C2 C2 C2</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>A3 A3 A3 A3 A3 </td>
                            <td>B3 B3 B3 B3 B3 </td>
                            <td>C3 C3 C3 C3 C3</td>
                        </tr>
                        <tr>
                            <td>A4 A4 A4 A4 A4</td>
                            <td>B4 B4 B4 B4 B4</td>
                            <td>C4 C4 C4 C4 C4</td>
                        </tr>
                    </tbody>
                </table>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: What's the deal with padding-bottom: 20010px;                  margin-bottom: -20000px; ?

Comment: I had it in there to have the columns the same height.
see http://www.positioniseverything.net/articles/onetruelayout/equalheight

Answer (score 0):

Set left padding on the center column equal to the width of the sidebar.

Does that make sense?

```
#center {
  padding-left:350px
}
```

Comment: BTW, it's 350, not 330 because you have an extra 10px of padding on both sides of the sidebar.

Comment: Adding the left-padding while keeping the width on #center results in the table getting cut-off at the side of the page
Removing the width:100 on #center has the full table but it is shifted down to start after the left column finishes.

Answer (score 0):

Try using this for #center:

```
#center {
   margin-left:330px;
   /*width:100%;*/
   padding-top:15px;
}
```

Comment: This results in the same thing as adding padding-left.
The table results don't start until the text in the left column ends.